# getting product id in laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5.1

hi i'm trying to get the product id from table products to insert it into the wishlist table and this is how the controller is :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Auth;
use App\User;
use App\Product;
use DB;

class listController extends Controller
{
    //
    public function getCreate(){

        $list=DB::table('wishlist')->get(['id','product_id']);
        $product=Product::get(['name','id','salary','image_name']);
        $user=Auth::user()->id;
        return view('contents.wishlist')->with('list',$list)
                                        ->with('product',$product)
                                        ->with('user',$user);
    }
    public function postCreate(Request $request){
        $id=$request->input('id');
        $user_id=Auth::user()->id;
        $product_id=Product::find('id');

        DB::table('wishlist')->insert(['id'=>$id,'user_id'=>$user_id,'product_id'=>$product_id]);
        return redirect()->action('listController@postCreate');
    }
}
```

what is the function i could use to get ?
and the view that show the list is that :

```
<form id="wishlist-view-form" action="{{ action('listController@postCreate') }}" method="post">
    <fieldset>
        <input name="form_key" type="hidden" value="inYgLvzSpOOWWVoP" />
        <table class="data-table" id="wishlist-table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th>Product Details and Comment</th>
                    <th>Add to Cart</th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach($product as $p)
                    @foreach($list as $l)
                        @if($p->id == $l->product_id)
                            <tr id="item_6">
                                <td>
                                    <a class="product-image" href="product_detail" title=" {{$p->name}} "> <img src="{{asset('images/')}}/{{$p->image_name}}" width="113" height="113" alt=" {{$p->name}} " /> </a>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <h3 class="product-name"><a href="product_detail" title=" {{$p->name}} "> {{$p->name}} </a></h3>
                                    <div class="description std">
                                        <div class="inner">The must-have tee for his third birthday!</div>
                                    </div>
                                    <textarea name="description[6]" rows="3" cols="5" title="Comment" placeholder="Please, enter your comments..."></textarea>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <div class="cart-cell">
                                        <div class="price-box" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
                                            <span class="regular-price" id="product-price-258"> <span class="price"  content="{{$p->salary}}">${{$p->salary}}</span> </span>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="add-to-cart-alt">
                                            <input type="text" class="input-text qty validate-not-negative-number" name="qty[6]" value="1" />
                                            <button type="button" title="Add to Cart" onclick="addWItemToCart(6);" class="button btn-cart"><span><span>Add to Cart</span></span></button>
                                        </div>
                                        <p><a class="link-edit" href="#">Edit</a></p>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <a href="#" title="Remove Item" class="btn-remove btn-remove2">Remove item</a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        @endif
                    @endforeach
                @endforeach
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <div class="buttons-set buttons-set2">
            <button type="submit" name="save_and_share" title="Share Wishlist" class="button btn-share"><span><span>Share Wishlist</span></span></button>
            <button type="button" title="Add All to Cart" class="button btn-add"><span><span>Add All to Cart</span></span></button>
            <button type="submit" name="do" title="Update Wishlist" class="button btn-update"><span><span>Update Wishlist</span></span></button>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: By the way what's your question?

Comment: how to get the product id from the products table and but it as product_id in the wishlist table as above ?

Comment: Please post your desired output..

Comment: what i want is to add products to my wishlist , as i press the button it adds the user id as shown above but the problem is the product it can't get the id of it

Comment: There is no `id` input in the form...? What actullay are you getting here `$request->input('id')` in your postCreate() function?

Comment: that's the id in the wish list not the product and it's auto increment

Comment: honestly I don't really understand your question but seems like a typo`$product_id=Product::find('id'); ` is wrong since you're inputting to find the string 'id' instead of the actual variable.

Comment: Does this make sense `Product::find('id')`? Do you pass any parameter to find method?

Comment: in this i'm trying to pass the id to the $product is it wrong ?

Comment: that should be `Product::find( $id )`;

Comment: i tried it right now but it gives me that error : SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'product_id' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `wishlist` (`id`, `user_id`, `product_id`) values (, 1, )) @BasheerAhmed

Comment: I already asked about `id` but you didn't mention where it's coming from? dd($request->id); and check out the result

Comment: are you not using relation between two tables(product/list) ?

Comment: no i don't the correct answer is down her u can take look at it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `html` inside `foreach` add another input to get product id

```
<input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="{{ $p->id }}" />
```

In your `postCreate()` method use this:

```
$product_id = $request['product_id'];

//or

$product_id = Input::get('product_id');
```

Comment: Actually, I was start writing earlier. But, suddenly go for Magrib Salah. After coming finished and post the answer ^_^ and thank you so much for accepting my answer.

Comment: No, Brother. Only you can accept answer in your question. I can upvote your answer and question. And I did.

Answer (score 1):

the answer of my question is that i hda to make a hidden input file to put the value of the product to, and the controller should be like that :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Input;
use Auth;
use App\User;
use App\Product;
use DB;

class listController extends Controller
{
    //
    public function getCreate(){

        $list=DB::table('wishlist')->get(['id','product_id','user_id']);
        $product=Product::get(['name','id','salary','image_name']);
        $user=Auth::user()->id;
        return view('contents.wishlist')->with('list',$list)
                                        ->with('product',$product)
                                        ->with('user',$user);
    }
    public function postCreate(Request $request){
        $id=$request->input('id');
        $user_id=Auth::user()->id;
        $product_id=Input::get('product_id');


        DB::table('wishlist')->insert(['id'=>$id,'user_id'=>$user_id,'product_id'=>$product_id]);
        return redirect()->action('listController@postCreate');
    }
}
```